# How to populate one-to-many/many-to-one tables with symfony2 forms?

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm new in Symfony and I'm stuck with populating one-to-many/many-to-one tables.
I managed to display the form but when I submit it I got the following error:

> Found entity of type AppBundle\Entity\Products on association AppBundle\Entity\Customers#customers_products, but expecting AppBundle\Entity\CustomersProducts

Here is my code:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use AppBundle\Entity\CustomersProducts;

/**
 * Customers
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="customers")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\CustomersRepository")
 */
class Customers
{


 /** @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="CustomersProducts", mappedBy="customers") */

 protected $customers_products;

  public function __construct()
    {
        $this->customers_products = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    } 


   public function getCustomersProducts()
    {
        return $this->customers_products->toArray();
    }

 public function setCustomersProducts($customers_products)
    {
     if (count($customers_products) > 0) {
        foreach ($customers_products as $i) {
            $this->addCustomersProducts($i);
        }
    }

    return $this;
    } 


    public function addCustomersProducts( $customers_products)
{


    $this->customers_products->add($customers_products);
} 

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="ip", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $ip;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return Customers
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set ip
     *
     * @param string $ip
     * @return Customers
     */
    public function setIp($ip)
    {
        $this->ip = $ip;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get ip
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getIp()
    {
        return $this->ip;
    }
}
```

Products.php:

```html
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
/**
 * Products
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="products")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\ProductsRepository")
 */
class Products
{


  /** @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="CustomersProducts", mappedBy="products") */
    protected $customers_products; 

     public function __construct()
    {
        $this->customers_products = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }
    /** 
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return Products
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
}
```

CustomersProducts.php

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * CustomersProducts
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="customers_products")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\CustomersProductsRepository")
 */
class CustomersProducts
{



    /** 
     * 
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Customers", inversedBy="customers_products") 
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="customer_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false) 
     */
    protected $customers;

    /** 
     * 
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Products", inversedBy="customers_products") 
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false) 
     */
    protected $products;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="version", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $version;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set version
     *
     * @param string $version
     * @return CustomersProducts
     */
    public function setVersion($version)
    {
        $this->version = $version;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get version
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getVersion()
    {
        return $this->version;
    }
}
```

CustomersType.php

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class CustomersType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name')
            ->add('ip')
            ->add('customers_products', 'entity', array(
                         'class' => 'AppBundle:Products',
                                     'multiple' =>true,
                                     'expanded' => true,
                                     'property' => 'name'           
            ));
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Customers'
        ));
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Symfony: Embed collection of forms for ManyToOne-OneToMany relation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23240500/symfony-embed-collection-of-forms-for-manytoone-onetomany-relation)

Comment: You are on the right track but your CustomerType meeds to map customers_products to CustomerProduct not Product.  Normally this sort of thing would work if you defined a ManyToMany relation.  Some majic goes on behind the scenes so you are not dealing with the join table directly.  But I am assuming you need additional properties on CustomerProduct.  I suspect you will probably end up needing to use a form collection as well: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html

Comment: Thank you for your answers!. So you think that I need to implement a form collection instead of entity. Right? I also need another entity (table Versions) where each product can have more than one version and user will choose first a product and after that a version for that particular product. Do you have any examples how to do that?

Comment: May you need change your CustomersType `'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Customers'` to `'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\CustomersProducts'`

Comment: No examples that would make much sense.  Just follow the book and make yourself a CustomerProductType.

Comment: @user3722402 did you ever get his solved?